# Count Distinct values from 2 columns

Tags: r

I need to get only distinct values that are spread over two columns and return the distinct values into one column. 
Example:

```
 colA colB
---- --------
darcy elizabeth
elizabeth darcy
jon doe
doe joe
```

It should return:

```
resultCol
darcy
elizabeth
jon
doe
```

Is there any builtin function or library that can do that more efficiently?

I tried a workaround to get the results but it is extremely slow for more than 100 thousands observations.

```
#First i create a sample dataframe
col1<-c("darcy","elizabeth","elizabeth","darcy","john","doe")
col2<-c("elizabeth","darcy","darcy","elizabeth","doe","john")

dfSample<-data.frame(col1,col2)

#Then i create an empty dataframe to store all values in a single column
emptyDataframe<-data.frame(resultColumn=character())

for(i in 1:nrow(dfSample)){
  emptyDataframe<-rbind(emptyDataframe,c(toString(dfSample[i,1])),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

for(i in 1:nrow(dfSample)){
  emptyDataframe<-rbind(emptyDataframe,c(toString(dfSample[i,2])),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

emptyDataframe

#Finally i get the distinct values using dplyr
var_distinct_values<-distinct(emptyDataframe)
```

Comment: `unique(unlist(dfSample))`

Answer (score 3):

I use union to get unique values across specific columns:

```
with(dfSample, union(col1,  col2))
```

---

**PS:** The answer from d.b in the comments is also another way.

You can improvise his answer if you have extra columns but want to run it only over specific columns:

```
unique(unlist(dfSample[1:2]))
```

This gets the unique values from first two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general purpose solution.
It's based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717428/count-distinct-values-from-2-columns/57717496#57717496) but can be extended to any number of columns as long as the object is a `data.frame` or `list`.

```
Reduce(union, dfSample)
[1] "darcy"     "elizabeth" "john"      "doe"
```

Now with 100K observations in each of 10 columns.

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 1e5
bigger <- replicate(n, sample(c(col1, col2), 10, TRUE))
bigger <- as.data.frame(bigger)

system.time(Reduce(union, bigger))
#     user    system  ellapsed
#    3.769     0.000     3.772
```

**Edit.**

After a second thought, I realized that the test above is run with a dataframe with a very small number of different values. A test with a larger number does not necessarily give the same results.

```
set.seed(1234)
s <- sprintf("%05d", 1:5000)
big2 <- replicate(n, sample(s, 10, TRUE))
big2 <- as.data.frame(big2)
rm(s)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  red = Reduce(union, big2),
  uniq = unique(unlist(big2)),
  times = 10
)
#Unit: seconds
# expr       min       lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld
#  red 26.021855 26.42693 27.470746 27.198807 28.56720 29.022047    10   b
# uniq  1.405091  1.42978  1.632265  1.548753  1.56691  2.693431    10  a
```

The `unique/unlist` solution is now clearly better.